# How to create a network of single organization in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have tried deploying a single organization in hypreledger fabric. First of all, i created a channel using the commands in hyperledger official documentation but i am not able to gain any appropriate help in building a single organization

Comment: Please share some errors or logs where you are stuck. Or do you want how to customize the connection profile for a single organization fabric network?

Answer (score 2):

If you're following `first-network` from the fabric-samples, then you have to modify a few things.

#### To create a single org network:

- Update the `docker-compose-cli`. Remove all the `org2` services and its references.

This will start a network with only one organization.

#### To create a channel with single org:

- Update the `configtx.yaml` and add a profile with single org.

```
OneOrgChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

- Create a new channel configuration `channel.tx` using `OneOrgChannel` profile.

```
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile OneOrgChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
```

- Create a new channel using the new channel configuration.

This channel is configured only for one organization. If you want another org in this channel then you have to update the channel configuration.